# How to make a background jobs get input from a socket in Unix-like OSs?

Tags: bash, sockets, process

How can I make a process get its standard input from a socket or a dynamic stream, which I can reference in the future for writing?

The scenario is like this:

Lets say I run a background job like `foo &`, in bash. I want it to read input from somewhere (a file, a socket, a descriptor or something else) that I can reference in the future, so that in case I want `foo` to do something by writing to its input I can do something like `echo "foos-instruction" >> file-where-foo-gets-its-input-from`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the program that the process is running is designed to read from `stdin`, you would use normal shell input redirection (`<`), for example:

`foo < file-where-foo-gets-its-input-from &`

or, more likely:

`tail -f file-where-foo-gets-its-input-from | foo &`

When you want `foo` to do something, you can do exactly what you described in your question:

`echo "foos-instruction" >> file-where-foo-gets-its-input-from`

...and `foo` will do whatever it's supposed to do with `foos-instruction`.

Et voila.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing named pipes.

```
mkfifo input
foo < input &

echo foo > input
```

A named pipe (also called a FIFO, for First-In, First-Out) is a limited-size buffer that the OS maintains and acts much like a file. Data written to the file can be read once, and bytes are read in the same order they are written. If the buffer is empty, a read will block until enough data to finish the read is written. If the buffer is full, a write will block until a read "drains" it enough for the write to complete.

Comment: Thanks so much! Yeap, that is just what I was looking for. Can you recommend any source from where I can learn about all this things of Inter Process Communication?